# Efficient algorithm for transforming a set with a function

Tags: python, algorithm, function, python-3.x

I'm writing a code that will count the gaps in the function `g(x)` below, with respect to the natural numbers, and then sum them.

```
from math import *

a = set()
n = eval(input("n = "))

def g(x):
    return floor(x*log10(x))   # thanks to tzaman

b = 1
while g(b) < n:
    a.add(g(b))
    b+=1

aprime = set(range(max(a)))

z = max(a)

print(z*(z+1)/2-sum(a))        # thanks to tzaman

input("Done!")
```

I am trying to have `n = 10 ** 10`, that is, `10000000000`, and perform calculations within a reasonable amount of time (say, < 10 minutes). However, this code performs ludicrously long, and I wonder: is there a more efficient way to do this?

---

### Example I/Os

```
n = 12, output = 15
```

### Other information

The following chart compares `x` to `g(x)`:

```
 x   | 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
g(x) | 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 7 8 10 11 12
```

The set `x \ g(x)` represents the members in `x` not in `g(x)`, and is, for numbers below 12, `{0,6,9}`; the sum of these is 15. So, when `n = 12`, `output = 15`.

Comment: Please, explain the problem, so we don't have to infer what your code is trying to do.

Comment: If `len(a)` is much much smaller than `len(aprime)` which it seems like it is in this case, you should just calculate `sum(a)` and subtract from the closed form of `sum(aprime)`: `a*(a+1)/2`

Comment: @JuanLopes `I'm writing a code that will count the gaps in the function g(x) below... However, this code performs ludicrously long...` I believe I stated my problem clearly; is it the unclear definition of a gap?

Comment: This is a website for programming problems so if your code is related to other subjects we may not be able to understand immediately. Always best to give example input and output if there something which may be unclear :)

Comment: Also, I'm hoping `g(x)` is just an example here -- if that's actually the function you're using then transforming it to `g(x) = floor(x*log10(x))` will be a lot faster for large `x`.

Comment: @tzaman Thank you for both of your optimizations. It was indeed my original function, but was a combination of a digit-counting function and the function `x**x`.

Comment: `g(x)` is also an increasing function of `x` if `x >= 1` and takes only integer values. So you can probably do a [ternary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_search) to determine at which points it switches between `x=1` and `x=n`.

Comment: try to calculate the scale of you expected problem, it's roughly `9.3*2^30`, that is 9.3G. presume your cpu is 4G and is very powerful, 2.2seconds are required just to iterate through all numbers. your 10 minutes requirement implies <300 clock cycles each iteration, with `log` and `set` these expensive ones, and your code is in python, it's probably not achievable.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr With the code as it is now, I am currently on the first step (setting `g(x)`). I am not entirely sure what you're saying, but I started the program about 20 minutes ago. It's still going, only on `855476`. a mere 0.008% done.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ i was showing you a brief argument about how impossible it's gonna finish everything within 10 minutes with the scale you specified(`n = 10 ** 10`).

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Oh, I see. Sorry, I misunderstood. What would your estimate be, for `n = 10 ** 10`, then?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ that's very coarse. python probably suffers `1/100` slowdown, and `set` is unpredictably expensive. to finish your while loop, a good several thousands or tens of thousands minutes are the very least estimation.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr It seems like you know a lot about the subject; you say that Python suffers a `1/100` slowdown&mdash;does that mean there are other, faster languages?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ that's not "official" at all. it's a rough scale estimation. there are of course languages considered commonly faster than python, like c/c++, java, c#, etc. any languages can be compiled into machine code will definitely faster than python.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr I see. I will consider moving to a compiled language in favor of speed. Thanks for your non-official rough estimations ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your troubles probably arise from the line `sum(aprime-a)`. This forces python to compute the set difference of your two sets. Considering how large your sets will be that is a **huge** waste of time.

Instead notice that `sum(a-b) = sum(a)-sum(b)` when `b` is a subset of `a` (as it is in your case). So we now have `sum(aprime)-sum(a)`.

Next take advantage of the fact that `aprime` is simply an arithmetic sequence! You have a formula to calculate the sum of those things! Instead of `sum(aprime)` you can do

```
maxVal = max(a)
sumAPrime = ((maxVal +1)*maxVal)/2
```

So you now have `sumAPrime - sum(a)` as your solution!

I am going to assume that you need the optimizations to work for any arbitrary function `g` and so you can't make assumptions about the function in your code.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: No, actually. `g` as stated is the function I wish to optimize, and is not arbitrary. As for your optimizations, I am sure if they will work better for large `n`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it would make much difference but you could prevent using `set()` and `eval()`. `eval()` could be changed to `int()` since you are already setting n = to the result of the input. Next you could check for the value of g(b) in a as it iterates. Removing aprime and changing a to a list will give the following.

```
from math import *

a = []
n = int(input("n = "))

def g(x):
    return floor(x*log10(x))

b = 1
while g(b) < n:
    if g(b) in a:
        b+=1
    else:
        a.append(g(b))
        b+=1

z = max(a)

print(z*(z+1)/2-sum(a))

input("Done!")
```

Comment: Doing it this way took about 5 mins or so to run using 10e6 so i imagine 10e10 is gonna take a while. a long while.